# SQL Server login fails for web app

Tags: sql-server, iis, iis-7.5

I have 2 web applications on the same web server (IIS 7.5 on Windows Server 2008) that connect to the same database(on a separate server). Both applications use the same connectionstring and both use the same application pool. The app pool uses a custom account for the App Pool Identity. One site works just fine but the other site gets "Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\ANONYMOUS LOGON" as soon as it attempts to connect to the database. Any suggestions on what the problem may be?

Comment: Not an expert of IIS, but you are using integrated security, and IIS is not sending the right user.

Comment: Thanks for your response. That's what my initial thought was too but both sites are using the same app pool - IRMWEBSITE in this case. IRMWEBSITE is setup to pass _IRM as the user. Site A works but Site B gets the error. There are actually 11 sites total using IRMWEBSITE. All work except the one.

Comment: I found the problem. In IIS, under the site's Authentication settings, I had to disable "ASP .NET Impersonation".

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. In IIS, under the site's Authentication settings, I had to disable "ASP .NET Impersonation".